# Why doesn't this activiy finish?

Tags: java, android

I have following code:

```
    mQuestions=DictionaryDbWrapper.getInstance().getQuestionsSequence(
            this.getIntent().getStringExtra(ApplicationUtilities.TEST_CATEGORY_PARAMETER), 50);
    mQuestionsCount=mQuestions.size();
    Log.e("count", String.valueOf(mQuestionsCount));
    if (mQuestionsCount==0) {
        Log.e("1", "111");
        Toast.makeText(this, "В данной категории нет слов", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.finish();
    }

    makeQuestion();
```

`mQuestions` is empty ArrayList, and I see that `count` equals 0 on Log always. Also I see `1/111` record on my Log always too. But my activity doesn't do a **finish** method!

`makeQuestion` is method that needn't work with empty `mQuestion` (it throw Exception). But If I make a comment for `makeQuestion` then `finish` method works well! Method for this code works on main thread (it is executed from `onCreate()` method).

Please, suggest where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The finish() function is non-blocking, this means that the execution will continue while the activity is finishing in background.

To solve your problem, add a return statement after the finish() call.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that calling `finish()` does not have the similar blocking effect of calling `return`.

Based on your code, you are assuming that `finish()` will have the same blocking effect of `return`.

Try this:

```
mQuestions=DictionaryDbWrapper.getInstance().getQuestionsSequence(
        this.getIntent().getStringExtra(ApplicationUtilities.TEST_CATEGORY_PARAMETER), 50);
mQuestionsCount=mQuestions.size();
Log.e("count", String.valueOf(mQuestionsCount));
if (mQuestionsCount==0) {
    Log.e("1", "111");
    Toast.makeText(this, "В данной категории нет слов", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    this.finish();
}
else {
    makeQuestion();
}
```